# How to use inverted border-radius?

Tags: html, css

I giving an indicator to menu items using border property and I want it to be rounded backwards as in the image below:

[image]

I tried using border-radius but this is the result:

[image]

Also feel free to suggest different approaches for implementing an indicator for sidebar menus in react since I'm not sure if this is possible using css properties.

Comment: The similar question tagged here is for inverting the rounded corners while my question is how to horizontally flip the rounded corners. I don't think they have the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use before and add an element to style

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}

div::before{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  width: 10%;
  top: 15%;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS-Tricks' Infinite Borders technique and applying border-radius. This method will require borders and box-shadow and not outline.

```
    img { border-radius: 4px;
 /* #1 */ border: 5px solid hsl (0, 0%, 40%);
 /* #2 */ padding: 5px; background: hsl (0, 0%, 20%);
 /* #3 outline: 5px solid hsl (0, 0%, 60%);
 */ /* #4 AND INFINITY......!!!
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer and use tag to insert code for more readability ? :) [See markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to the shape that I want. could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Mate, Atleast post your code with the question so that people can help you and advise you how to correct it.

P.S - I know this belongs in the comment and not an answer but I am new to Stack Overflow and I don't have points to comment on anything

Comment: Mate, There is no code; This is pure css and I think I clearly showed the desired shape with images.